# Which statement do people usually call the Decomposition Theorem, and what is the precise reference for it?

Tags: decomposition-theorem, reference-request, perverse-sheaves, ag.algebraic-geometry

Which statement is usually called the Decomposition Theorem (for perverse sheaves)? Is this (roughly): a proper pushforward of an intersection complex could be decomposed into a direct sum of (shifted) intersection complexes (or is it something more general, or possibly something less general)? Which theorems of [BBD] should one combine to get the 'usual' formulation of the decomposition theorem?

Comment: I would understand the decomposition theorem to be precisely the result that you state in your second sentence.

Comment: There is an excellent survey article in a recent issue of BAMS that might help, here's the PDF link: http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2009-46-04/S0273-0979-09-01260-9/S0273-0979-09-01260-9.pdf

Comment: Mikhail, it is basically what you said, although there are some
additional "purity" hypotheses, without which it can fail. The decomposition theorem is is given in [BBD, 6.2.5].

Comment: In my comment above (as Donu Arapura's comment indicates), "precisely" is too strong a word.  One form of the theorem says that pushing forward *the* IC complex upstairs (i.e. the one associated to the trivial local system) gives a direct sum of IC complexes of semisimple local systems downstairs; this is what I was thinking of when I made my comment.  A more general version of the theorem (the one that Donu Arapura is referring to) describes the pushforward of IC sheaves attached to pure local systems upstairs.  I think all this is discussed in the article that Dave Anderson links to.

Comment: Thanks; I know this paper. Yet it doesn't seem to contain a precise reference to BBD.

Comment: Also, it seems that Theorem 6.2.5 of BBD does not mention intersection complexes?

Comment: Probably the missing link is the statement that the IC complexes of pure local systems are pure (coupled with the fact that the trivial local system is pure); see Theorem 3.1.6 of the linked paper.

Comment: Theorem 6.2.5 of BBD does not mention intersection complexes, but they are hiding in the statement. It mentions semi-simple perverse sheaves, and we know from theorem 4.3.1 of BBD that any simple perverse sheaf is the intersection complex of a local system on a locally closed subscheme. 